# How do I update data in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to update my already existing user. But I really do not know how to do it.

this is the API route that I am using to update the user

```
Route::put('/user/{user}', [UserController::class, 'updateUser']);
```

The function in the usercontroller is this:

```
public function updateUser(Request $request, User $user){
        $data = $request->validate([
            'username' => '',
            'firstname' => '',
            'lastname' => '',
            'email' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'phone_number' => '',
            'role' => '',
            'companyID' => '',
            'companyRole' => '',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        $user->update($input);
        return $user;
    }
```

This is the function that I use in vue to send the new user data to laravel:

```
editUser(){
            console.log(this.user)
            this.$axios
                .put('api/user/' + this.$route.params.id + this.user)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        }
```

This is the "this.user"

```
{ "id": 1, "username": "user", "firstname": "user", "lastname": "user", "email": "user@test.com", "email_verified_at": null, "phone_number": 6282223, "role": "user", "companyID": 2, "companyRole": "employee", "logged_in": 0, "created_at": "2021-11-11T12:00:23.000000Z", "updated_at": "2021-11-11T12:00:23.000000Z" }
```

And the "this.$route.params.id" is just the user id

I do not know what I am doing wrong. It is not updating

Comment: Did you mean `.put('api/user/' + this.$route.params.id, this.user)`? Your original code seems to be trying to concatenate `this.user` (an object) into the URL

Comment: @Phil is that wrong?

Comment: Your original code will attempt to make a PUT request to `api/user/1[object%20Object]`. Probably not what you want

Comment: @Phil okay, and how do I have to do it so it is going to work?

Comment: Is my first comment not clear? If it's still not working after that, use the tools at your disposal (browser dev-tools _Network_ panel especially) to debug the issue

Comment: @Phil omg im so dumb i just had to put a "," instead of a "+" thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel param binding can give you the user by only passing the id.

The main error here is how you are calling your API.

Change axios from this:

```
this.$axios.put('api/user/' + this.$route.params.id + this.user)
```

To this:

```
this.$axios.put(`api/user/${this.$route.params.id}`, this.user)
```

This way laravel will **recive the ID and convert it to the user**, also recive the **payload sended in "this.user"**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would try another approach in order to update a user with specific id.

In web.php file where you define your Routes put:

```
Route::get('/update_user', '\App\Http\Controllers\PostController@update_user');
```

In your Controller in my example PostController:

```
public function update_user()
{
   //Find all users 
   $users = DB::select('select * from users');

   foreach($users as $user){
       //UPDATE
       DB::update('update users set email = "userTest@test.com" where id = ?',[4]);
   }

   //If you want echo an alert message for the result
   echo '<script>alert("The email of user with id = 4 has been updated.")</script>';

}
```

Try to shape the code for your needs, but the basic idea is the above.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't accept the incoming user because even do, that you (the person) knows the user exists that may not be the case for all users that are sent.

You should only send the ID and then based on that ID look for the user in the DB and then only then when u are sure that the user exists, it should updated.

REQUEST:

```
editUser(){
            console.log(this.user.id)
            this.$axios
                .put('/api/user/' + this.user.id)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        }
```

API ENDPOINT:

```
Route::put('/user/{id}', [UserController::class, 'updateUser']);
```

UPDATE FUNCTION:

```
public function updateUser(Request $request, $id){
    $data = $request->validate([
        'username' => '',
        'firstname' => '',
        'lastname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'phone_number' => '',
        'role' => '',
        'companyID' => '',
        'companyRole' => '',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($input);
    $user->save();
    return $user;
}
```